# Pension tax as a Swiss citizen in Germany for less than 5 years

Tags: germany, switzerland, pension

I'm a Swiss citizen who has recently moved to Germany for short term employment (<5 years). I do not speak German. Since I will work here for less than 5 years, I can request to be exhempted from the "Pflichtversicherung in der Zusatzversorgung", which I believe is what in Switzerland is called AHV/AVS.

- If I *do not* request this, what happens to the contributions I paid when I leave Germany? Can I have them transferred to my AHV/AVS contributions?
- If I do request it and end up staying in Germany for more than 5 years (very unlikely but you never know), will I have to pay retroactively?

Comment: I think you are confusing the **gesetzliche Rentenversicherung** with *Pflichtversicherung in der Zusatzversorgung*. The first is a mandatory pension, the second is an extra pension that only employees have that work in public services (öffentliche Dienst). Please clarify. The first is transferrable, if a treaty between Germany and Switzerland exists (which I assume is the case). Look for **Versicherungsverlauf** on this site.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Thanks, I'm confused, I called a Swiss office about the AHV and they told me that it is *not* tranferrable because Germany is in the EU, and as part of the bilateral agreements I have to pay it in the EU country I live in. But now you say this is another thing. Do you know where I could read what the "Pflichtversicherung in der Zusatzversorgung" exactly is in English? (Or French or Italian)?